# Php Form - Why are all fields required?

Tags: php, isset

I have a contact form that will only submit if all the fields are completed. I don't want this as many fields are optional. I believe it has to do with this part of my code, but I am unsure how to change it and removing it will post the form automatically when the page opens.

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['address_line_2'], $_POST['city_state_zip'], $_POST['phone_number'], $_POST['email_address'], $_POST['bedrooms'], $_POST['baths'], $_POST['square_feet'], $_POST['basement'], $_POST['garage'], $_POST['house_style'], $_POST['price_range'], $_POST['construction'], $_POST['heat'], $_POST['features'], $_POST['comments']))
```

For context here is the rest of the code.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

include_once "/usr/share/pear/Swift/swift_required.php";

// Check if the form has been posted
if (isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['address_line_2'], $_POST['city_state_zip'], $_POST['phone_number'], $_POST['email_address'], $_POST['bedrooms'], $_POST['baths'], $_POST['square_feet'], $_POST['basement'], $_POST['garage'], $_POST['house_style'], $_POST['price_range'], $_POST['construction'], $_POST['heat'], $_POST['features'], $_POST['comments'])) {

// The email address the email will be sent to
$to = 'emailaccount@website.com';
// Set the from address for the email
$from = 'emailaccount@website.com';

$headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";

// The email subject
$subject = 'Contact Form Submission';

// Build the body of the email
$mailbody = "The contact form has been filled out.\n\n"
          . "first_name: " . $_POST['first_name'] . "\n"
          . "last_name: " . $_POST['last_name'] . "\n"
          . "address: " . $_POST['address'] . "\n"
          . "address_line_2: " . $_POST['address_line_2'] . "\n"
          . "city_state_zip: " . $_POST['city_state_zip'] . "\n"
          . "phone_number: " . $_POST['phone_number'] . "\n"
          . "email_address: " . $_POST['email_address'] . "\n"
          . "bedrooms: " . $_POST['bedrooms'] . "\n"
          . "baths: " . $_POST['baths'] . "\n"
          . "square_feet: " . $_POST['square_feet'] . "\n"
          . "basement: " . $_POST['basement'] . "\n"
          . "garage: " . $_POST['garage'] . "\n"
          . "house_style: " . $_POST['house_style'] . "\n"
          . "price_range: " . $_POST['price_range'] . "\n"
          . "construction: " . $_POST['construction'] . "\n"
          . "heat: " . $_POST['heat'] . "\n"
          . "features: " . $_POST['features'] . "\n"
          . "comments:\n" . $_POST['comments'];
// Create the mail transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.domainhere.com', 587);
$transport->setUsername('emailaccount@website.com');
$transport->setPassword('123456');
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
// Create the mail
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setTo($to);
$message->setBody($mailbody);

// Send the mail
$result = $swift->send($message);
}
if ($result) 
{ 
header('Location: http://www.domainhere.com/thankyou.html'); }
?>
```

Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're not sure how to remove the optional parameters from the isset call and you want us to do it for you? this is the easiest programming task you could possibly have. try doing any research, literally any research at all and i'm sure you will quickly figure it out.

Comment: hell, don't do any research. give it a try by yourself. i bet you'll still get it.

Comment: You might get more help if at least you tell us which fields are optional.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['address_line_2'], $_POST['city_state_zip'], $_POST['phone_number'], $_POST['email_address'], $_POST['bedrooms'], $_POST['baths'], $_POST['square_feet'], $_POST['basement'], $_POST['garage'], $_POST['house_style'], $_POST['price_range'], $_POST['construction'], $_POST['heat'], $_POST['features'], $_POST['comments']))
```

requires everything there to be filled in.